# Keeping floating divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="childA">123</div>
    <div id="childB">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
</div>

<style>
    #childA, #childB {float:left}
</style>
```

I want `#childB` to stay on the right of `childA`, but the problem is that when there is a lot of text inside it, it goes below `#childA` - I want to simply grow in height once it has reached the width of `#container - #childA`.

I cannot set the width of it as I don't know how much text will be in `#childA`. (`#childA` will never have much text inside it, and should stay at only 1 line.)

Thank you for any help - spent some time looking, and couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: Can you set width to #childB?

Comment: Want it to take up the whole rest of width of container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a `max-width` with `max-width:#container - #childA;` on `#childB` to prevent that.

edit:

another way: remove `float:left;` from `childB` and add `overflow:hidden` and add a max-with to `childA` like `max-width:80%`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5wwvJ/)**

Comment: I wrote that I don't know how much text will be in #childA, so I don't have its width

Comment: @jadegem Nonetheless the only option to prevent this problem is to set either `width` or `max-width`

Comment: Perhaps you have a way without floats?

Comment: when your first div have lot of text 2nd div go hide...please check.
http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/5wwvJ/2/

Comment: @CSSGuy just add a max-width to fix this.

Comment: @Christoph Check the question "I cannot set the width of it "

Comment: @CSSGuy "will never have much text inside it" - so your scenario will most likey not occur. And that doesn't change the point that you posted your answer 10minutes after Jezen and used exactly his solution, ignoring the question and the comments to Jezens answer. But if you feel better by downvoting my accepted answer, no problem. BTW nice "Hacked By Elie D"-Comment on your site.

Comment: i won't have any issue that your answer accepted sory if you mind my question i just want to improve my knowledge i have add max-width but it's not working please check http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanabbasi/5wwvJ/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your #childB is wrapping under #childA because the two elements are too wide to fit side-by-side in their parent container.

Try this:

```
#container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#childA, #childB {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: childA has to be as wide as the text inside it, not 50%

Comment: You need to be able to declare width on *something*

Comment: unfortunately white-space: nowrap; will not help here, but work against what he's trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

set a width of your childA and childB use class like that

```
#childA, #childB {float: left;width:50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="childA">123</div>
   <div id="childB">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
</div>

<style>
    #childA {
      float: left;
    }
</style>
```

so your `#childA` div will float left of `#childB` and they won't wrap one under the other, but the downside is that the text of `#childB` will wrap underneath #childA once its height passes `#childA` height